# cmake build directory, Windows VS macOS

Tags: c++, windows, macos, cmake, makefile

Typical cmake produre here was:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/vcpkg.cmake
cmake --build .
```

That worked on both Windows and macOS.

Howver on Windows the binary in placed under `build/Debug/mylib.dll` while on macOS it is placed directly under `build/libmylib.dylib`. How can I make it on `build/Debug/libmylib.dylib` on macOS too?

Comment: That comes down to which build generator you're using.  Check the documentation for the generators available on your mac, and look for anything that's multi-config.

Comment: Most likely you don't need what you are asking for. You better ask what you really want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply manually reproduce the same directory structure yourself on the Mac.

However, I would definitely make sure to only put a `Debug` configuration in a directory called Debug, lest you confuse yourself in the future:

```sh
mkdir Debug
cd Debug
cmake ../.. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/vcpkg.cmake 
cmake --build .
```